# How to run a HTML file from server which includes Cordova plug-ins?

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Cordova and lastly I have created an html file and added to xampp/htdocs and worked fine, basically I want to make a generic app. But now I want to create an app that uses Camera Plug-in but I cannot access to camera even if I add plugins folder to both cordova app folder and htdocs folder. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call them in your index.html and have added the cordova.js before invoking the plugins ? 
cordova works heavily on the stacks and it reads it accordingly. So if your calling your file transfer first then call it after calling the cordova.js(it contains instance for camera)

Comment: do I have to place plugin files to both server and applicaton?

Comment: yes. But i would suggest to store them on the application itself and not call them through the server. Can you tell me what exactly are trying to achieve? i maybe able help you better.

Comment: simple, using camera plugin I want to make an app that takes photo. when I run the html from project there is no errors, but when I put the html to www folder and call that html from app the camera plugin doesn't work.

Comment: how are you calling the camera in your html ?